# Negative lookaheads in Grammar-Kit

Tags: intellij-idea, grammar-kit

Is there a way to do a negative lookahead in Grammar-kit?

Example: I have two tokens defined A and B and would like the define the a rule that matches A if it is not followed by B.

I tried to find it in this [grammar](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/blob/master/grammars/Grammar.bnf), but I am not able to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammar-Kit is based on PEG ([Parsing Expression Grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar)).

- Positive lookahead: `&XXX`
- Negative lookahead: `!XXX`